# Drag and Drop. e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = Copy is not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code returns true or false if the operation isCopy drop

```
export const copy = (e) => e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed === "copy";

export const copy = (e) => e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed === "all" ||
e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed === "none" ||
e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed === "move";
```

It works on chrome, but firefox is just giving me `effectAllow: uninitialized`